# facebook sharing issue in iphone sdk

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, facebook

Whenever I am sharing video or image on Facebook using Facebook ios sdk, it got shared only with the administrator account but from any other account it gives me error. For example I created an application from my Facebook account, when I login to my app using my account, I am able to share video/photos. But when I log in with any other Facebook account, the share item is not visible on the wall and Facebook SDK throws the following error:

```
Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0xa822830 {com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=403, com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
    body =     {
        error =         {
            code = 200;
            message = "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action";
            type = OAuthException;
        };
    };
    code = 403;
```

Any help on this issue is highly appreciated.

Comment: i know this problem facebook restricted 30th april on wards if u want this permission send it request facebook .......

Comment: if u want more details go to facebook developer site..

Comment: how to send it to facebook

Comment: after posting image or video u r getting any postid or nothing. if not getting any post id no need to send facebook just conform it i will send u posting image code..

Comment: while I am posting video or image it is not giving me id it straightaway give me this error response.

Comment: which permission u r using..

Comment: publish_action and publish_stream we are using

Comment: otherwise compulsary u have to send to request facebook..